# Savon 2.11.1 set soap header after client is instantiated Rails + SSRS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, reporting-services, savon, soapheader

I'm trying to integrate my rails app with a Sql Server Reports Services (SSRS) using Savon 2.11.1. I'm using the ReportServicesExecution2005 WSDL. The problem I have is that I have to add a session_id to the soap header after the client has been instantiated. This is because the session_id is generated by SSRS after the client makes a call to load_report.

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: "https://somewsdl.asmx?wsdl", basic_auth: ["user", "pass"])
```

this call returns the session_id in the response:

```
response = client.call(:load_report, message: {report: "path/to/report"} )
```

the soap header needs to contain the session_id in the client when this call is made:

```
client.call(:set_execution_parameters, message: { report: "path/to/report", parameters: params  }  )
```

Tried this but it didn't work:

```
client.call(:set_execution_parameters, soap_header: {"session_id" => @session_id}, message: { report: "path/to/report", parameters: params  }  )
```

I get the following error:

> (soap:Client) The session identifier is missing. A session identifier
>   is required for this operation.  --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.MissingSessionIdException:
>   The session identifier is missing. A session identifier is required
>   for this operation.

Thanks for the help an advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found(while clunky) was to create a new client via Savon and pass the existing client values plus the new execution_id/session_Id into the constructor. This did the trick. Code example below.

Initial Savon Client:

```
@exeClient = Savon.client(wsdl: "some_wsdl.asmx?wsdl", basic_auth: ["user", "pass"], 
convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase, soap_header: {"execution_id" => ""} )
```

call load_report to get execution_id:

```
@data = @exeClient.call(:load_report, message: {report: "/path/to/report"} )
```

Access execution_id:

```
@report = @data.to_hash

@execution_id = @report[:load_report_response][:execution_info][:execution_id]
```

Create new client that has access to run the report via the execution_id:

```
@newClient = Savon.client(wsdl: "/path/to/report/wsdl", basic_auth: ["user", "pass"], 
 :soap_header => {:"tns:TrustedUserHeader" => {"tns:UserName"=> "" , "tns:UserToken" => ""},  :"tns:ExecutionHeader" => {"tns:ExecutionID" => @execution_id}})
```

Create Params Hash:

```
param1 = { :Parameter_value =>{
    :"Name" => "nameOfParam",
    :"Value" => current_user.company_id
  }
}
```

Call setExecutionParameters:

```
response =  @newClient.call(:set_execution_parameters, message: { "Parameters" => param1} )
```

Now it works. Note that its important how you specify namespaces with Savon. If you don't do it correctly, the namespace will not be specified on some tags; which will make the soap call fail.

Comment: I also want to point out that the "TrustedUserHeader" and all sub tags were requires to make this work regardless if they were blank or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the soap_header hash to pass session id like

```
response = client.call(:set_execution_parameters, :soap_header => { :session_id => sid })
```

Cheers

Comment: This only sets the soap_header in locals and Savon passes globals in client.rd. I'm still getting the same error and session_id is still blank in the soap_header when I try your solution.